# Animation Play State Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have a fairly simple question, but I can't seem to find a clear explanation. 
What and how do I target with the javascript function webkitAnimationPlayState?

```
__.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
```

I can't figure out what to put in the __ to direct the function to the appropriate animation (in my css file, it is currently "paused").

The line above is in a script tag in the head of my html file. I want it to run an animation that I've paused in my css file.

Someone suggested writing:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
```

But I still can't figure out how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: Your last line of code is correct, but what do you mean by saying _But I still can't figure out how to use it_? what you exactly want to do?

Comment: in my css file i have written body{  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;}. i want to know how to switch that state to "running" in my index.html file. writing document.getElementById("body")--- doesn't work. i'm unclear on how to point to the right animation using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read up on ".getElementById" and it came together. The function requires just that, an "id", so I gave my body an id attribute to use as function input and it worked out.

```
<script> 
    function myfunction() {
    setTimeout(function(){window.location.href = "home.html";}, 2000);
    document.getElementById("body").style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";}
</script>

<body id="body">
```